# How to resolve TypeError?

Tags: python

```
from __future__ import division
import urllib,urllib2
import urllib
import json
from math import log


def hits(word1,word2=""):
    query = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=%s"
    if word2 == "":
        results = urllib.urlopen(query % word1)
    else:
        results = urllib.urlopen(query % word1+" "+"AROUND(10)"+" "+word2)
    json_res = json.loads(results.read())
    google_hits=int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
    return google_hits


def so(phrase):
    num = hits(phrase,"excellent") * hits("poor")


    den = hits(phrase,"poor") * hits("excellent")

    ratio = num / den

    sop = log(ratio,2)
    return sop

print so("beautiful product")
```

I require the above code to calculate the semantic orientation of a given phrase(or string).

When I execute the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\nltkexp\ddddd.py", line 32, in <module>
    print so("beautiful product")
  File "C:\Python27\nltkexp\ddddd.py", line 24, in so
    den = hits(phrase,"poor") * hits("excellent")
  File "C:\Python27\nltkexp\ddddd.py", line 16, in hits
    google_hits=int(json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How to resolve this error? Can someone point out where I am going wrong with the code?

Comment: Easy: Find out which expression/value is `None`. Then *don't* invoke a method (or indexer) upon it. Use `if` statements as guards when required.

Comment: Search for the error message and you'll find *many* questions that would be duplicates if only the core problem was isolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing `json_res['responseData']['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']`, the problem is

`json_res` or `json_res['responseData']` or `json_res['responseData']['cursor']` might be `None` and its can't access `key` of the `NoneType` object.

Please print `json_resp` and check which keys are available in that.

Comment: Or `json_res and json_res.get('responseData') and json_res['responseData'].get('cursor') or 0` if `google_hits` is not necessary